# Error: argument "no" is missing, with no default

Tags: r

I am trying to create three new columns that are the appropriate human-readable summary for a diagnosis. For example If diag_1 is <400 then returns "neoplasm". When i try to run the code, I get an error: Problem with `mutate()` input `diagnosis1`. x argument "no" is missing, with no default ℹ Input `diagnosis1` is `ifelse(...)`.

Here is the code I have:

```
diabiates %>% 
    mutate(diagnosis1 = ifelse(diag_1 > 140, "infection", 
                               ifelse (diag_1 > 130, "digestive", 
                                       ifelse(diag_1 <20, "neoplasm"))))
```

```
                  
  encounter_id diag_1 diag_2 diag_3
1   182795622   428 410 491
2   185569164   428 403 682
3   68184246    428 401 413
4   217930950   415 401 272
5   94628052    648 659 250
6   116653320   414 411 493
7   75331956    730 707 731
8   100954620   428 414 250
9   137518212   427 427 427
10  284406012   715 276 414
11  101488188   403 250 250
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need the `no` value at the last `ifelse`.  As it is a nested `ifelse`, the 'yes' value for first `ifelse` is "infection", and the `no` is based on the output of second `ifelse`.  Similarly for the second `ifelse`, the 'no' is from the third `ifelse`.  But, in the last or third `ifelse`, there is no input for "no".  We can specify `NA_character_` to fill that

```
library(dplyr)
diabiates %>% 
    mutate(diagnosis1 = ifelse(diag_1 > 140, "infection", 
                           ifelse (diag_1 > 130, "digestive", 
                              ifelse(diag_1 <20, "neoplasm", 
                  NA_character_))))
```

---

Also, instead of nested `ifelse`, this could be done with `case_when` in a more readable way

```
diabiates %>%
    mutate(diagnosis1 = case_when(diag_1 > 140 ~ "infection",
                      diag_1 > 130 & diag_1 <= 140 ~ "digestive",
                      diag_1 < 20 ~ "neoplasm"))
```

As it is processed sequentially, the second condition can also be `diag_1 > 130`.  But, writing things explicitly makes it easier to understand when we read the same code in the future

---

Or it can be done using `cut` or `findInterval`

```
diabiates %>%
    mutate(diagnosis1 = cut(diag_1, breaks = c(-Inf, 20,  130, 140),
        labels = c("neoplasm", "digestive", "infection")))
```